# Fragment returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, oncreate

I am aware this issue has been brought up and resolved multiple times but none of the solution I looked at helped me so here comes again:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);
        try {
             userInfo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showData);
            user myUser = new user();
                userInfo.setText(myUser.getUserInfo());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        }
            return rootView;
    }
```

That is my fragment (the default created by Android Studio with minor edits). The corresponding XML layout is this:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeScreen$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/showData" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The error I'm getting:

```
03-19 08:23:09.119  29125-29125/com.app.myAPP I/System.out﹕ ERROR: null
03-19 08:23:12.296  29125-29125/com.app.myAPP I/System.out﹕ ERROR: null
```

The TextView is created in OnCreateView() instead of onCreate() which seems to cause a null return most of the time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post you full java code please, so far is not enough to tell what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Check if `R.id.showData` is in fact, inside of `R.layout.fragment_home_screen`.
Also, Change this:

```
userInfo.setText(myUser.getUserInfo());
```

to

```
userInfo.setText("hello");
```

to verify if myUser was correctly initialized.